# Помогите сверстать чат

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, chat, blocks

Нужно расположить блоки в виде чата, как на картинке. Помогите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так и как это сделать правильнее, чище?

```css
.text-align-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
    direction: rtl;
}

.item {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div {
    display: block;
}

.person {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 30px;
    direction: ltr;
}

.all-chat {
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>homework 5</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hw.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="text-align-center">Chat</h1>

    <div class="all-chat">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="person">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/40/50" alt="photo" class="image">

                <div class="text">
                    <div class="data">9:03</div>
                    <div class="message">Hi</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="person">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/40/50" alt="photo" class="image">

                <div class="text">
                    <div class="data">9:05</div>
                    <div class="message">Hello!</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _.item:nth-child(even) {_ - а если у тебя будет несколько сообщений подряд от одного пользователя? Сделай просто отдельный классы для отправленного сообщения и для принятого сообщения. Может быть даже стоит в них разметку разную сделать

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Даю общие советы и перехожу к деталями вашего кода:

1. При вёрстке интересуйтесь предназначением CSS-свойств. То есть довод использования — просто потому что "так работает" используйте в последнюю очередь (если всё остальное не работает).

   К примеру, вы используете свойство `direction`.  Это свойство предназначено для указания направления текста. В большинстве языков текст пишется слева направо (значение `ltr` по умолчанию), но на арабском и иврите текст пишется справа налево и для этого текста указывается `direction: rtl;`. Получается, что вы используете это свойство не по назначению.
2. Осмотрительней используйте абсолютное позиционирование. В идеале его использовать *только* когда нужно чтобы элементы перекрывали другие и элемент извлёкся из потока отображения. К примеру, модальные окна, выпадающие списки с более сложным отображением, чем стандартный `select` и т.д. Также используется для в некоторых рецептах вроде поместить иконку внутри текстового поля. Но в данном случае не вижу в потребности в абсолютном позиционировании.
3. С большой осторожностью используйте псевдоселекторы (к примеру, `first-child;`, `only-child`, `nth-child` и т.д.). Потому что псевдоселекторы

   - игнорируют видимый блок или нет. То есть если вы скроете один из блоков с помощью `display: none`, он всё равно будет учитываться при применении псевдоселектора.
   - при применении учитывают лишь порядковый номер элемента относительно родителя. То есть псевдоселектор `.item:nth-child(even)` работает так "выбрать каждого чётного ребёнка, у которого есть класс `item`", а **не так** "выбрать каждый чётный элемент с классом `item`". Иллюстрирую примером:

     ```css
     .item:nth-child(even) {
       background-color: red;
     }
     ```

     ```html
     <div class="container">
       <div class="not-item">
         One (not item)
       </div>
       <div class="item">
         Two (item)
       </div>
       <div class="item">
         Three (item)
       </div>
       <div class="not-item">
         Four (not item)
       </div>
       <div class="item">
         Five (item)
       </div>
       <div class="item">
         Six (item)
       </div>  
     </div>
     ```

   Если вы добавите элементы рядом с `.item`, вёрстка может сломаться.

   Поэтому рекомендую посмотреть, может стоит задавать отдельные классы для особых типов элементов.

---

В данном случае, я полагаю также, что чат означает, что может быть несколько сообщений подряд от одного пользователя. Поэтому применение стилей только к чётным элементам, кажется неверным.

4. Изучите flexbox. Расположение элементов с помощью `float`, `clear`, `vertical-align` не обладает такой мощью и не такое гибкое и сопровождаемое.
5. Изучите CSS-методологию. BEM или SMACSS. Для того, чтобы вы могли легко менять вёрстку, а также если такие же блоки или подобные нужны на других страницах вы бы их без проблем добавляли и меняли. В примере, я буду использовать BEM.
6. Не используйте безликие или неоднозначные имена вроде `.item`. Это же может быть что угодно. Применение этого класса зависит от того, кто в нём родитель и что рядом находится. А это значит, что если где-то добавится блок `.item`, то те же стили для него и применятся, что, возможно, будет нежелательно. Относитесь к селекторам также как к переменным. У них должно быть строго определённое предназначение и имя должно чётко его отражать. Если вы назовёте, к примеру, `chat-item`, то уже более ясно значение этого блока.
7. Относитесь к вёрстке как к программированию, для которого важна легкость восприятия, гибкость и сопровождаемость. Также не менее важно соответствие стандартов. Вёрстку портят дублирования кода, старайтесь их избегать. Использование современных препроцессоров с переменными, циклами, условиями делает вёрстку почти неотличимой от программирования.

---

#### Результаты

Для каждой серии сообщений создал блок `.chat-item`, где будет находиться аватар и одно или несколько сообщений от пользователя.

Для того, чтобы применять стили для инвертирования расположение (для отвечающего) колонки я задал `flex-direction: row-reverse;`, что инвертирует порядок расположения элементов.

Здесь использована методология BEM.
Для того, чтобы не создавать дополнительные классы для вложенных элементов при инвертировании я пожертвовал чистотой BEM и добавил селекторы с вложенностью (`.chat__item--responder .chat__message`, `.chat__item--responder .chat__message-content`). По самой методологии (в идеале) следует использовать только классы без вложенности.

В результате код может выглядеть так:

```css
.chat__header {
  text-align: center;
}

.chat__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.chat__person-avatar {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.chat__messages {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.chat__message {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.chat__message-content {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 7px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.chat__item--responder {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

  .chat__item--responder .chat__message {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
  }

  .chat__item--responder .chat__message-content {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="chat"> 
  <h1 class="chat__header">Chat</h1>

  <div class="chat__content">
    <div class="chat__item">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/40/50" alt="photo" class="chat__person-avatar">
    
      <div class="chat__messages">
        <div class="chat__message">
          <div class="chat__message-time">9:03</div>
          <div class="chat__message-content">Hi</div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="chat__message">
          <div class="chat__message-time">9:03</div>
          <div class="chat__message-content">How are you?</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="chat__item chat__item--responder">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/40/50" alt="photo" class="chat__person-avatar">
    
      <div class="chat__messages">
        <div class="chat__message">
          <div class="chat__message-time">9:05</div>
          <div class="chat__message-content">Hello</div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="chat__message">
          <div class="chat__message-time">9:07</div>
          <div class="chat__message-content">I'm fine. Let's have a dinner today.</div> 
        </div>
        
        <div class="chat__message">
          <div class="chat__message-time">9:07</div>
          <div class="chat__message-content">What do you think about it?           </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Обратите внимание на изменение порядка элементов при помощи `order`, в остальном — всё стандартно.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.chat {
  padding: 40px;
}

.message {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.message--user-1 + .message--user-2,
.message--user-2 + .message--user-1 {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
.message--user-1 + .message--user-1,
.message--user-2 + .message--user-2 {
  margin-top: .5em;
}
.message__time {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 5px 50px;
}
.message__author-pic {
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.message__text {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #69b4f3;
  background-color: #bfe2ff;
  max-width: 70%;
}

.message--user-2 {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.message--user-2 .message__time {
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0 50px 5px 0;
}
.message--user-2 .message__author-pic {
  order: 1;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}
.message--user-2 .message__text {
  background-color: #69b4f3;
}
```

```html
<section class="chat">
  <div class="message message--user-1">
    <time class="message__time">21.02.2017 21:12:07</time>
    <figure class="message__author-pic">
      <img src="http://pipsum.com/40x40.jpg">
    </figure>
    <div class="message__text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis at purus nibh. Cras metus nulla, vestibulum in auctor ac, fermentum vitae tellus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message message--user-2">
    <time class="message__time">21.02.2017 21:12:07</time>
    <figure class="message__author-pic">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/40/40/people">
    </figure>
    <div class="message__text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis at purus nibh. Cras metus nulla, vestibulum in auctor ac, fermentum vitae tellus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message message--user-2">
    <time class="message__time">21.02.2017 21:12:07</time>
    <figure class="message__author-pic">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/40/40/people">
    </figure>
    <div class="message__text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis at purus nibh. Cras metus nulla, vestibulum in auctor ac, fermentum vitae tellus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message message--user-1">
    <time class="message__time">21.02.2017 21:12:07</time>
    <figure class="message__author-pic">
      <img src="http://pipsum.com/40x40.jpg">
    </figure>
    <div class="message__text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis at purus nibh. Cras metus nulla, vestibulum in auctor ac, fermentum vitae tellus.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

Я к примеру сделал так, правда не самый лучший вариант. Но советую воспользоваться каким-нибудь фреймворков для таких затей.

```css
.text-align-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.item:nth-child(even) {
  direction: rtl;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.item-2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  right: 0;
  top: 200px;
}

div {
  display: block;
}

.person {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 50px; /* Отступ справа */
  margin-left: 50px; /* Отступ слева*/
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 30px;
  direction: ltr;
  background: #cccccc; /* Цвет фона под заголовком */
  color: black; /* Цвет текста */
  padding: 2px; /* Поля вокруг текста */
}

.all-chat {
  width: 500px;
}

.date{
      background: #cccccc; /* Цвет фона под заголовком */
      color: black; /* Цвет текста */
      padding: 2px; /* Поля вокруг текста */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>homework 5</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hw.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 class="text-align-center">Chat</h1>

    <div class="all-chat">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="person">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/40/50" alt="photo" class="image">

          <div class="text">
            <div class="date">9:03</div>
            <div class="text">Hi</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item-2">
        <div class="person">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/40/50" alt="photo" class="image-2">

          <div class="text">
            <div class="date">9:05</div>
            <div class="text">Hello!</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```